# Translation of empty string shows po header

Tags: python, django, gettext, po, django-i18n

When I try to translates empty strings in a django template I end up with the po header showing up instead an empty string http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#The_PO_File_Header .
I have to translate empty strings because they are in db an I can't fill all models and translate them as they are dynamic.
Now I use something like

```
{% if data %}
    {% trans data %}
{% endif %}
```

I tried to mark the header as fuzzy but it didn't work.

Is there any way to avoid to check each translatable string and avoid the po header showing up ?
I am using django 1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found out what was going on, according to [Why does gettext translate an empty string to the .po header text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610144)
and http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#MO-Files

> Having the original strings sorted enables the use of simple binary
>   search, for when the MO file does not contain an hashing table, or for
>   when it is not practical to use the hashing table provided in the MO
>   file. This also has another advantage, as the empty string in a PO
>   file GNU gettext is usually translated into some system information
>   attached to that particular MO file, and the empty string necessarily
>   becomes the first in both the original and translated tables, making
>   the system information very easy to find.

So I can't avoid checking the string.